# How to get Windows XP style default Alt-Tab behavior in Windows 7 without Administrator's privileges?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry, alt-tab

I'd like to get the to the more usable Windows XP style <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behavior by disabling Aero Peek by default when using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and not have to press and release the second <kbd>Alt</kbd> key first each time I want to navigate but I do not have administrator privilege to edit `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` add a `DWORD` with name `AltTabSettings` and Value `1`.  Neither do I have permission to access the Advanced section of the System control panel.

Is there any other way to get the old <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behavior by default if I don't have permission to edit the registry or the advanced System control panel?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Kindly use below steps.

1. Go to System Properties (right click “Computer” in an explorer window and choose properties)
2. Click “Advanced System Settings” in the left panel
3. You should be on the Advanced Tab, in the performance section, click “Settings…”
4. Uncheck “Enable Aero Peek”

Comment: No dice, need Administrator privileges on my machine to access Advanced Systems Settings.